# Why isn't the file created or why can't the path be found?

Tags: java

So I am creating the following code to create a new file. Does anyone know why it's throwing the exception?

Essentially, I thought it was going to check if a file exists after using the constructor and it doesn't, I thought it would create it but neither happened.

```
Java Code:


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.File;

class CreateNumberFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Ask user for filename and highest number
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the filename");
        String fileName = in.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the highest number for this file");
        int maxNumber = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("A file titled " + fileName+ " will be created containing a");
        System.out.println(" string of numbers with numbers ranging from 0 to: " + maxNumber);

        // Create a File object 
        File myFile = new File("home/Users/Joe/Dropbox/Programming/Java/Projects/g2.txt");
        // Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract 
        //pathname exists.
        if (myFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath() +
                    " File already exists");

        } else {
          try{
            //creates a new, empty file named by this pathname
            myFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath() + 
                    " File Created Successfully");
          } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println ("Caught IOException "+e.getMessage());
          }
        }

    }//main
}//class
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

Output:

```
Caught IOException The system cannot find the path specified
```

I thought the code would check if the file exists and if it doesn't, I would use the constructor to create the file? any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using in.nextLine() to get the file name instead of next()?

Comment: This is likely cause by the path to where you want to create file not existing.  You can check by using `myFile.getParentFile().exists()` and make the path with something like `myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()`

Answer (score 0):

Your path looks like an absolute path, but you seem to have forgotten the slash at its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If your file doesn't `exist()`, it could happen that it's parent files don't `exist()` either, so you should create them:

```
try {
    // create all dirs needed to myFile's parent to exist()
    myFile.getParent().mkdirs();
    //creates a new, empty file named by this pathname
    myFile.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath() + " File Created Successfully");
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println ("Caught IOException "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Additionally, you are missing the root `/` in `myFile`'s path, [as Alexey Feldgendler said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13557142/641451).

Comment: The Parent directory does exist. I literally went to the folder in Windows 7 and copies the address from the address bar. However, I was getting an "illegal escape" error, so I changed the slashes to the other ones.

Comment: @bigsonny so the problem was you were using the wrong slashes? Have you resolved it? Post & accept your own answer if that's the case. Haven't you got to add the initial `/` or `C:\ ` to your path? Maybe you can prepend `file:///` for this to work universally.